# Semilogarithmic plot (semilogy) ignores zeros in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a CSV file which includes three columns. I basically want to read the first two columns and then draw a `semilogy` plot with the values. I have the following code segment:

```
filename = 'ber.csv';
M = csvread(filename, 1)

close all
figure 
semilogy(M(:,1), M(:,2), 'sb-', 'LineWidth', 2);
grid on
axis([0 25 10^-3 10^0])
xlabel('traceback depth, TB')
ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
title('BER with Viterbi decoding')
toc
```

The above code segment, draws something like this for me:

[image]

The problem is that it stops somewhere around 24 on the x-axis, whereas I have 30 values. The last 10 values can be seen below (rest omitted for brevity):

```
   20.0000    0.0807        
   21.0000    0.0443    
   22.0000    0.0312        
   23.0000    0.0078        
   24.0000    0.0052        
   25.0000         0        
   26.0000         0         
   27.0000         0         
   28.0000         0         
   29.0000         0         
   30.0000         0
```

I want the plot to continue until 30, and for it to hit the x-axis, while the rest of the values from 25 to 30, are just 0. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to be more specific on how does this looks like. Technically, the 0 is infinitely below in a logarithmic plot.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Is there any way, to make the graph look like it hits the x-axis, I mean show that y value "reaches" 0?

Comment: You don't want to "hit" the x-axis, as if the data has a value of 10^-3. That would be a misrepresentation of your data. You could maybe replace 0 by a very, very low number, say 10^-50 and limit the y-axis to not show those values. That would show a line starting from point 24 going far down, which can be interpreted in the manner you are looking for.

Comment: Actually this question is hardly about programming by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have a coding problem here, you have a math problem. If you type `log(0)` into MATLAB, you'll get the answer `-Inf`. MATLAB does not know how to plot `-Inf` on a finite screen.

You say you want your line to hit the x-axis, but notice that the bottom of your axis is 0.001. What if the x-axis moves down to 0.00001? You won't hit the axis anymore. You need to think hard about what you are trying to convey when displaying your data.

If you just want to extend down to the axis, the "simplest" thing you could do would be to try to extrapolate down to the x-axis and add a point in there and plot it.

```
figure 
h = semilogy(M(:,1), M(:,2), 'sb-', 'LineWidth', 2);
grid on
axis([0 25 10^-3 10^0])
axis([0 25 10^-3 10^0])
xlabel('traceback depth, TB')
ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
title('BER with Viterbi decoding')

% Get the y limits
y_limits = ylim;

% Find the bottom x-axis
bottom_y_limit = min(y_limits);

% interp1 doesn't like repeated values so throw out the extra zeros
first_zero = find(M(:,2) == 0, 1, 'first');

% Figure out where your plot hits the x-axis.    
new_point = interp1(M(1:first_zero, 2), M(1:first_zero, 1), bottom_y_limit, 'pchip');

% Insert the new point into your data
Mnew = sortrows([M; new_point, bottom_y_limit]);

% Replace the data vector in the plot with the new data that includes the extra point
set(h, 'XData', Mnew(:, 1), 'YData', Mnew(:, 2));
```

Some important caveats to this are that this is pretty static, so if you change your axis limits, your new point won't hit the axis anymore. To get that to work would require setting up a callback function for your axes. Also, this should work because your sample data is pretty monotonic in how it goes to zero. If your data oscillates at all, the interpolation will fail. I also only tested this on the subset of your data that you posted. Since the interpolation is done with the data "sideways", to get to the x-axis, if you have noise in your data such that the y-axis is no longer monotonic, you may also have to do some tweaking to pick only 1 or 2 points near where it plunges to zero instead of lazily sticking the whole vector in like I've done.

Using data you posted above:

```
M=[20.0000    0.0807        
   21.0000    0.0443    
   22.0000    0.0312        
   23.0000    0.0078        
   24.0000    0.0052        
   25.0000         0        
   26.0000         0         
   27.0000         0         
   28.0000         0         
   29.0000         0         
   30.0000         0  ];
```

The output I get is:
[image: Output plot]

Comment: When I tried the above code segment, I get the following error message `Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`. Then it goes on and plots exactly the same thing as in my original post.

Comment: When I copy and past your list of values for `M` in your post, I get an 11x2 matrix. Your error sounds like when you read your data in with `csvread`, your getting a 2xN matrix, so transpose it. The error is coming in because I'm assuming columnar data so I can use the `sortrows` command.